# Rename folders with the names given in a text list

Tags: windows, list, powershell, directory, rename

In one folder, I have 200 folders named D_1, D_2, ..., D_200.
I have a text file containing the new names I want for these folders:
Name1
Name2
...
Name200
(I obtained this list from a column of an excell spreadsheet.)
So I want these changes of names: D_1 -> Name 1, ..., D_200 -> Name200.
I am on Windows 8.1 (not pro), with the Powershell installed.
How can I do this renaming using Powershell or the regular windows command line?

Comment: You can use `Rename-Item`

Comment: How? The original names are regular: D_1 to D_200. But the new names are not, eg they are given by the list: xyut, azdgkj, ..., jtyu (what I called Name1 is really xyut, .. and Name200 is jtyu)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is sort the original folders from `D_1` to `D_200`, iterate over them in a loop and rename them to the corresponding name from the file with `Rename-Item`:

```
# Read new names from file
$newNames   = Get-Content .\file\with\new\names.txt

# Retrieve existing folders and sort by the number in their name
$oldFolders = Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\folders\ -Filter 'D_*' -Directory | Sort {$_.Name.Split('_')[1] -as [int]}

for($i = 0; $i -lt $oldFolders.Count; $i++)
{
    # Rename each folder
    Rename-Item $oldFolders[$i].FullName -NewName $newNames[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
Matthias's answer seems great.

I found another way.
I create a csv file with the old names and the new names:
old,new
D_1,xuty
...
D_200,dvodjvov
Then I copy paste this command in the shell:

```
    $csv = Import-Csv old_new.csv
    foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Rename-Item $line.old $line.new
    }
```

It worked (on 5 folders).
The only downside is I have to fill in the old names in the left column of my csv.